# Returning IWICStream / IStream from unmanaged C++ DLL to managed C# and reading it

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, dllexport

Within a C# program I would like to receive image data (probably in the form of `IStream`), returned from a function imported from an unmanaged C++ DLL.

I have read several similar questions and msdn docs on this general topic but so far have been unable to figure out a complete working solution.

C++ function exported for consumption in managed C#:-

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IStream* GetImage(){

    IWICBitmap *pBitmap = NULL;

    //... Code emitted for clarity
    //... Bitmap creation and Direct2D image manipulation
    //...

    IWICStream *piStream = NULL;
    IStream *stream;
    CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &stream);
    HRESULT hr = piStream->InitializeFromIStream(stream);

    //... pBmpEncoder is IWICBitmapEncoder, piBitmapFrame is IWICBitmapFrameEncode
    //... pFactory is IWICImagingFactory

    hr = pFactory->CreateEncoder(GUID_ContainerFormatTiff, NULL, &pBmpEncoder);
    hr = pBmpEncoder->Initialize(piStream, WICBitmapEncoderNoCache);
    //...
    hr = pBmpEncoder->CreateNewFrame(&piBitmapFrame, &pPropertybag);
    //..
    piBitmapFrame->WriteSource(pBitmap, &rect);
    //...
    piBitmapFrame->Commit();
    pBmpEncoder->Commit();

    return stream;

}
```

I have emitted code for the sake of clarity. What is important is that an `IWICBitmap` is encoded as a `.tiff` to an `IWICStream`. The `IWICStream` was initialized from an `IStream`. Then the function returns `*IStream`.

C# Imported function declaration:-

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream;

[DllImport(@"D:\mydlls\getimagedll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern IStream GetImage();
```

C# code consuming `GetImage()` function and attempting to read `IStream`:-

```
public ActionResult DeliverImage()
    {
        IStream stream = GetImage();

        unsafe
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[4000];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int* ptr = &bytesRead;
            stream.Read(fileBytes, fileBytes.Length, (IntPtr)ptr);

        return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.Tiff, "image.tiff");
        }
    }
```

There are three things I need help with.

1. Currently the C++ function is returning `*IStream` although the imported C# declaration has `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream` as return type. Obviously an `IStream` pointer and `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream` do not match. I have tried returning an IStream object from the function but intellisense warns 'function returning abstract class is not allowed'. How can an `IStream` be returned and correctly marshalled to be a managed C# `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.IStream`?
2. When reading the `IStream` in C#, how can the length of image data in the stream be discerned so that the read buffer can be set to the correct length?
3. What is the correct way to release the IStream in C++ or C# or both so that there isn't a memory leak? Can the stream be released in C++ as soon as it is returned or does there need to be a second function exported to C# that is called after the C# has finished using the stream?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: This looks very unhealthy, you completely ignore error handling.  Use the .NET TiffBitmapDecoder class instead, it already uses IWICStream.

Comment: I need to work in C++ so that I can use d2d and WIC for image manipulation. Please understand that I have tried to simplify the code to present just the key aspects of the question. The final solution should definitely have error handling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code to return `IStream*` works fine. Here is a simple demonstration that shows that it works fine:

**C++**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) IStream* __stdcall GetStream()
{
    IStream *stream;
    CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &stream);
    int i = 42;
    stream->Write(&i, sizeof(int), NULL);
    return stream;
}
```

**C#**

```
[DllImport(dllname)]
private static extern IStream GetStream();
....
IStream stream = GetStream();
IntPtr NewPosition = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(long));
stream.Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_END, NewPosition);
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.ReadInt64(NewPosition));
stream.Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_SET, IntPtr.Zero);
byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
stream.Read(bytes, 4, IntPtr.Zero);
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0));
```

How do you find the size of the stream? Well the code above shows how to do that using the `Seek` method. You'd want to wrap that up. For instance:

```
static long GetStreamSize(IStream stream)
{
    IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(sizeof(long));
    try
    {
        stream.Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, ptr);
        long pos = Marshal.ReadInt64(ptr);
        stream.Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_END, ptr);
        long size = Marshal.ReadInt64(ptr);
        stream.Seek(pos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, IntPtr.Zero);
        return size;
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(ptr);
    }
}
```

Or a bit more simple with unsafe code if you prefer:

```
unsafe static long GetStreamSize(IStream stream)
{
    long pos;
    stream.Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_CUR, new IntPtr(&pos));
    long size;
    stream.Seek(0, STREAM_SEEK_END, new IntPtr(&size));
    stream.Seek(pos, STREAM_SEEK_SET, IntPtr.Zero);
    return size;
}
```

Finally, you ask how to release the `IStream` interface in C#. You don't need to. The C# compiler takes care of the reference counting automatically. It inserts appropriate calls to `AddRef` and `Release`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your generous help!